# Sum column which only contain sum function

Tags: ms-office

In Excel, how can I sum a column, which contains numbers and its total using sum function, but I need to add cells which has sum function?

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in Excel for Mac as of yet that would recognize if a cell has the sum function inside and then sum only those cells. If you need a sum of the sums in a given column without repetition, you should for example point to the cells for the individual sums manually or put them in consecutive cells in a row or column and point to those cells as a single range in a sum function.